# FTP csv file from Unix server to Oracle DataBase through ODI

Tags: unix, ftp, oracle-data-integrator

We have a CSV files being loaded automatically in Unix machine.
Requirement: We need to load the csv file from that remote server to my oracle DB. We do have an ODI as our ETL tool. Can someone advice on how to proceed further. What is the way to load the CSV from Unix server to Oracle DB.Please help us with some document if this case is possible.

Thanks ,
Gowtham Raja S

Comment: Which version of ODI are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is providing some tutorials (Oracle By Example), one of them explains how to load a flat file to an Oracle table with ODI 12c : https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:112:::::P112_CONTENT_ID:7947

You will just need to change the field delimiter to a comma instead of a tab.
The other tutorials can be found on the product page : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/data-integrator/learnmore/index.html

Comment: Hi Jerome, Thanks for sharing your thought. But the links you have shared only shows how to work with flat file in our local machine. But i need to pick a flat file from a remote server. Can you please share the documents on ODI FTP and SFTP. Please , help me on the same.

Comment: If you execute your job using a standalone agent installed on the server instead of using the local agent (internal to ODI Studio), you can directly process files from the server. If you need to get the files from a remote location using FTP or SFTP protocol, you can create an ODI package and use the OdiFtpGet and OdiSftpGet tools available in the toolbox on the left side. You will find a lot of information about that in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

if you know how to create a data store for file, in ODI we have a LKM called LKM file to Oracle (SQLLDR) OR LKM file to Oracle (external table), both can be used to load data quickly, or if you feel like this is bit difficult, however since you have the Sqlldr to load data manually from file to DB, what ever the command you are using to start sqlldr place it in ODI procedure with technology as OSCommand whihc loads data automatically.

let me know if any other suggestios are required.